# Giving permissions to SYSTEM to write to a folder on Windows Server running on a Domain

Tags: permissions

We have a .NET application running on Windows Server 2012 R2 on IIS 6.2. It needs to write Excel files to a network folder on Windows Server 2012 R2.

It does this using Microsoft.Office.Interop, which is very difficult to run with IIS. The only way we have found to get it to work is to set the App Pool to Advanced Settings->Process Model->Itentity: LocalSystem. We tested writing a file locally, and was created by "SYSTEM". But it reports "Access to the path '...' is denied." when it tries to write to the network folder.

We can't seem to find a way to add permissions for SYSTEM on the client to the network folder. Has anyone had any experience with this, or are we going to need to find a way to run this as an actual account or IUSR?

Comment: so many red flags. System is a local account, so you cannot give it privledges to do anything on another box. its capability is unrivaled within itself, but cannot be used to access remote resources that are not anonymously accessible. generally on a domain you will want to run the application pool as a domain user that has access to all the required remote and local resources.

Comment: The correct way to address the issues you are having, is by rearchitecting your application to seperate concerns, so you can configure the different components seperately. for instance a windows service would probably be best for your document generation (your office interop) while your website should always be run as a least-privileged user, but can be run as a domain user to be able to move your files as required.

Comment: also, look for a third party library that can help you with your office interop. its a bad idea to have office on your webserver in the first place, and interop is really at best a cobbled together kludge, that works very very badly for non-interactive sessions. if it ever tries to display ANY notification at all, the process will lock, waiting on someone on an invisible desktop to press a non-existent OK button. its only safe for interactive desktop applications.

Comment: Yea, what Frank said. Don't do this. Tell us the problem you're actually trying to solve BEFORE you got this idea and we may be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: We will be looking for an alternative library. I understand completely that System is not a good account to use, but the requirement to use it is from Microsoft's library, not me.